# Why can't I store data inside my .txt file?

Tags: java, file, class, oop, instance

This is a workout app that I'm working on. The idea is to create an account(text file) and store the data that you enter inside it. Here's what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean start = true;

    while (start == true) {

        CreateNewMember();
        start = DecideToAddOrQuit();
    }
}


public static void CreateNewMember() {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.println("Enter a username: ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    createMember member = new createMember(input);
    member.setMembership();
    member.setInfo();
}

public static boolean DecideToAddOrQuit() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.println("\nPress 1 if you want to continue adding data.");
    out.println("Press any other key if you want to leave.");

    String decision = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (decision.equals("1")) {
        out.println("");
        return true;
    } else {
        out.println("Goodbye!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's the class responsible for adding data to the file:

```
public class createMember {

public String name;
private String fullName;
private String age;
private String experience;

private Formatter x;

public createMember(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setMembership() {
    try {           
        x = new Formatter(name);   
        out.println("File with name \"" + name + "\" has been created!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("Could not create username.");
    }
}

public void setInfo () {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fullNameIn, ageIn, experienceIn;

    out.println("Enter your Full Name");
    fullNameIn = keyboard.nextLine();
    fullName = fullNameIn;
    out.println("Enter your Age");
    ageIn = keyboard.nextLine();
    age = ageIn;
    out.println("Enter your lifting experience\n");
    experienceIn = keyboard.nextLine();
    experience = experienceIn;
    x.format("%s\t%s\t%s", fullName, age, experience );
 }

}
```

The values that I enter(fullName, age, experience) are NOT stored in the username file. How do I fix this and why is it occuring?

Comment: if you don't know what's wrong then how do you know it's not working? That is to say, can you at least tell us the problem you are having?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I added more info at the bottom now.  "The values that I enter are NOT stored in the username file. How do I fix this and why is it occuring?"

Comment: Right now - none. The values that I want to store are fullName, age and experience. They are located in the public void setInfo() method

Comment: If you are check the file via a text editor while the program is still running then you might need to [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#flush()) your formater in order to see the data in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting output to be written as the program is running, you may not see it because `Formatter` [buffers the output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.lang.String%29).

You must [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#close%28%29) the file when you are done with it (`x.close()`) so that any remaining buffered data is written (this does not happen automatically, even on program exit). Also if you want the output to actually be written immediately, [`flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#flush%28%29) it as soon as you write a line (`x.flush()`).

Comment: Not having close() was the issue. Thank you Jason!

Answer (score 0):

This question is not the clearest, but as far is I'm concerned you haven't ever told anything to actually write the data to a file at all. You should use `PrintWriter`. This will load the data you want into the file. Plus, in your code, your file is never created.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class createMember {

public String name;
private String fullName;
private String age;
private String experience;

// private Formatter x; not quite sure what this does. There seems to be no need for it.

PrintWriter write;

File f;    

public createMember(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setMembership() throws Exception {
    try {           
        // x = new Formatter(name);
        f = new File (name);
        f.createNewFile(); // This throws a HeadlessException (i believe, as it might be a FileNotFoundException instead)
        out.println("File with name \"" + name + "\" has been created!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("Could not create username.");
    }
}

public void setInfo () throws Exception {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fullNameIn, ageIn, experienceIn;
    write = new PrintWriter(f.toString()); // This throws a FileNotFoundException
    out.println("Enter your Full Name");
    fullNameIn = keyboard.nextLine();
    fullName = fullNameIn;
    write.println (fullName);
    out.println("Enter your Age");
    ageIn = keyboard.nextLine();
    age = ageIn;
    write.println(age);
    out.println("Enter your lifting experience\n");
    experienceIn = keyboard.nextLine();
    experience = experienceIn;
    write.println(experience);
    //x.format("%s\t%s\t%s", fullName, age, experience );
    write.close(); // Be sure to close it, or it gives a warning and the file is never written.
 }

}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for and happy coding!